# The distribution of the difference between two correlated non-central t distribution

Tags: distributions, t-distribution, differences, non-central

Suppose a binormal population $\{X, Y\}$ with means $\mathbf{\mu} = \{\mu_1,\mu_2\} \ne \{0,0\}$ and covariance $\Sigma= \sigma^2\begin{bmatrix}1 & \rho\\ \rho &1 \end{bmatrix}$. Let $S^2$ be an estimator of $\sigma^2$ with $f$ degrees of freedom.

It is known that the variates $\{X/S, Y/S\}$ follows a bivariate non-central $t$ distribution (e.g., [Kshirsagar, 1961](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/CD5F06D1A1B030BB22232B61A345F4B2/S0305004100034885a.pdf/some-extensions-of-the-multivariate-t-distribution-and-the-multivariate-generalization-of-the-distribution-of-the-regression-coefficient.pdf)).

[Walgren (1980)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2287194) derived the distribution of the product $X/S \times Y/S$. Is there a derivation for their difference, $X/S - Y/S$?

**Edit:** In the present context, I use the pooled standard deviation, that is the mean of the separate standard deviations,

$$S_X = \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X})^2 / (n-1)$$
$$S_Y = \sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\bar{Y})^2 / (n-1)$$

with $ S = \sqrt{ (S_X^2 + S_Y^2)/2 }$. This estimate of $\sigma$ is independent of both $X$ and $Y$, and as shown [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/482459/143790)  is a chi-square distribution with degrees of freedom $2(n-1)/(1+\rho^2)$.

Comment: Please state *which* estimator of $\sigma^2$ you have in mind.  (At least three would be natural in this setting and there are many others one could use as well.)

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: I don't have a "derivation" but I'm getting $\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{v+1}{2}\right) \left(2 (1-\rho ) \sigma ^2 v\right)^{v/2} \left(2 (1-\rho ) \sigma ^2 v+(-\mu_1 +\mu_2+z)^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2} (v+1)}}{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{v}{2}\right)}$ for the pdf using *Mathematica* with $Z=X/S-Y/S$.

Comment: Do you mean that $(n-1)S^2/\sigma^2$ has a chi-square distribution with degrees of freedom $2(n-1)/(1+\rho^2)$ ?

Comment: @JimB The result from Ben in the link provided indicates that $2(n-1)/(1+\rho^2) S^2 / \sigma^2 \sim (1+\rho^2)/(2(n-1)) \chi^2_v$ in which $v = 2(n-1)/(1+\rho^2)$.

Comment: Thanks.  My point was that the chi-square distribution does not apply to $S$ as stated in the question  but rather a multiple of $S^2$ which should be made explicit.

Comment: @JimB: If I am not mistaken, the noncentral t distribution was generalized by Kshirsagar, 1961, to include any sort of variance estimates. Could that version of the non-central t distribution be applicable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134711/discussion-between-jimb-and-denis-cousineau).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that shows how to obtain a numerical approximation to the probability density function of $Z=X/S-Y/S$.  (I haven't been successful in finding an analytic solution.)

Using the joint density of $X/S$ and $Y/S$ found in Kshirsagar 1961 (as given in the question):

```
r = {{1, \[Rho]}, {\[Rho], 1}}; (* Correlation matrix *)
\[Mu] = {\[Mu]x, \[Mu]y};
t = {x, y};
f = 2 (n - 1)/(1 + \[Rho]^2); (* Degrees of freedom for estimate of S^2 *)
jointPDF = (Exp[-\[Mu] . Inverse[r] . \[Mu]/(2 \[Sigma]^2)]/(\[Pi] f Sqrt[ Det[r]] Gamma[f/2]))*
  Sum[(2^(\[Alpha]/2) (t . Inverse[r] . \[Mu])^\[Alpha]  Gamma[(f + 2 + \[Alpha])/2])/
  (\[Sigma]^\[Alpha] f^(\[Alpha]/2) \[Alpha]! 
  (1 + t . Inverse[r] . t/f)^((f + 2 + \[Alpha])/2)), {\[Alpha], 0, \[Infinity]}];
jointPDF = FullSimplify[jointPDF, Assumptions -> {-1 < \[Rho] < 1, \[Sigma] > 0, n > 1, 
    n \[Element] Integers, \[Mu]x \[Element] Reals, \[Mu]y \[Element] 
     Reals, x \[Element] Reals, y \[Element] Reals}]
```

A more readable version of the code is below:

[image: Code to obtain joint distribution]

The result is

[image: joint distribution of X/S and Y/S]

The pdf of the difference $Z = X/S - Y/S$ can be found numerically by replacing $y$ with $x-z$ and then integrating over $x$:

```
(* Numerical estimate of pdf of X/S - Y/S for a few values of n \
(sample size for estimating \[Sigma])*)
pdfz100 = 
  Table[{z, 
    NIntegrate[
     jointPDF /. {y -> x - z, 
       n -> 100, \[Sigma] -> 2, \[Rho] -> 1/2, \[Mu]x -> 1, \[Mu]y -> 
        3}, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]}, {z, -6, 3, 1/10}];
pdfz4 = Table[{z, 
    NIntegrate[
     jointPDF /. {y -> x - z, 
       n -> 4, \[Sigma] -> 2, \[Rho] -> 1/2, \[Mu]x -> 1, \[Mu]y -> 
        3}, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]}, {z, -6, 3, 1/10}];
pdfz2 = Table[{z, 
    NIntegrate[
     jointPDF /. {y -> x - z, 
       n -> 2, \[Sigma] -> 2, \[Rho] -> 1/2, \[Mu]x -> 1, \[Mu]y -> 
        3}, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]}, {z, -6, 3, 1/10}];
ListPlot[{pdfz100, pdfz4, pdfz2}, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotLegends -> {"n = 100", "n = 4", "n = 2"},
 PlotLabel -> 
  Style["\[Sigma] = 2, \[Rho] = 1/2, \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Mu]\), \
\(x\)]\) = 1, \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Mu]\), \(y\)]\) = 3", Bold, 18]]
```

Again, a more readable version:

[image: Code to find pdf of z]

The results follow:

[image: pdfs for various parameters]

As a check one should perform some simulations.

```
parms = {\[Sigma] -> 2, \[Rho] -> 1/2, \[Mu]x -> 1, \[Mu]y -> 3, n -> 2};
nsim = 100000; (* Number of simulations *)
(* Data for x and y *)
data = RandomVariate[
  BinormalDistribution[{\[Mu]x, \[Mu]y}, {\[Sigma], \[Sigma]}, \[Rho]] /. parms, nsim];
(* Data to for estimating S *)
xy = RandomVariate[
   BinormalDistribution[{mu1, mu2}, {\[Sigma], \[Sigma]}, \[Rho]] /. 
    parms, {nsim, n /. parms}];
s = Sqrt[(Variance[#[[All, 1]]]/2 + Variance[#[[All, 2]]]/2) & /@ xy];
(* Z = X/S - Y/S *)
zz = data[[All, 1]]/s - data[[All, 2]]/s;

(* Numerically estimate the pdf of z *)
pdfz = Table[{z, NIntegrate[jointPDF /. y -> x - z /. parms, 
  {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]},
   {z, Quantile[zz, 0.005], Quantile[zz, 0.995], (Quantile[zz, 0.995] - Quantile[zz, 0.005])/200}];

(* Plot the results *)
Show[Histogram[zz, "FreedmanDiaconis", "PDF"], 
 ListPlot[pdfz, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: Results of simulations]

There seems to be a match.